# app crashing when trying to move to a cardview activity

Tags: android

i suddently get the following error in my app and it crashes. i dont get any specific errors from my code, so i cannot find anything in the code to fix.

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getScreenWidthDp(Landroid/content/res/Resources;)I in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ConfigurationHelper; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ConfigurationHelper' appears in /data/app/tsakiris.com.aggelies-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes2.dex)
                         at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.getSizeDimension(FloatingActionButton.java:442)
                         at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.getSizeDimension(FloatingActionButton.java:434)
                         at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.onMeasure(FloatingActionButton.java:189)
                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                         at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2636)
                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1193)
                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1400)
                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1078)
                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5875)
                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5351)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

do you have any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: I think Floating Action Button have you declared correctly.Associated compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
 this dependency added? Because our question is vague elaborate the issue or share us the code

Comment: thank you. it wasnt exactly that but you gave me the idea. i updated all the dependencies to the latest.

Comment: Still remains the issue?

Comment: no it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the same version of compileSdkVersion and dependency version.
`compileSdkVersion 26
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'`